# Rotation error in overflow div IE 8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, rotation

I have a div with contains an image that have to rotate whenever the user click the zoom bottom. Once the user click the link, a div that holds the image display in with 100 z-index(to the top). The image has a container in that div for when zooming it in, the scrolls bars appers(which means that the div that holds the image is overflow:scroll;)

But here the problem:

If the user zoom the image to 300, then the scrolls activate but, once that click to rotate, the X scroll doesnot appear, which causes displaying just a part of the image. If the image'withd is bigger than the div container, which is overflow:scroll, the x scroll should let me scroll left or right to see the image entirely.

Here in-live example:

[image]

Here my code:

css:

```
#img_container {
    overflow-x:scroll;

    overflow-y:scroll;

    position:relative;

    width:800px;

    height:500px;
    }

/*the rotation code*/

    #rotate_80deg {

    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1);
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="image-Viewer">
  <div id="image_container><img src="src..." />
</div>
```

Comment: IE's `filter` style with it's activeX controls has a very large number of known issues, especially when combined with other browser features. I would not be surprised at all if it goes wrong when combined with `zoom`. There's a good chance that you're hitting a browser bug, and if so, there's a good chance there's no real way around it.

Comment: Well, i used a work around: Imitate zoom with height and width property. I had no option and works very well...